# ConfigurationErrorsException is found in both ServiceStack and System.Configuration.ConfigurationManger assemblies (netstandard)

Tags: servicestack

I use both the ServiceStack and System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager package in my .NET Standard library. I reference the `ConfigurationErrorsException` class specifically. My Visual Studio doesn't build because it doesn't know which assembly `ConfigurationErrorsException` is from.

The dotnet team has ported the `System.Configuration` namespace to netcore, so maybe now it's time to remove it from the ServiceStack assembly?

#### Source References

The System.Configuration namespace in ServiceStack: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/0b84a5a638d4230e6211eba554796980fcdc1f3b/src/ServiceStack/Platforms/PlatformNetCore.cs

System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager/

Source for ConfigurationErrorsException in the System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager package: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/a10890f4ffe0fadf090c922578ba0e606ebdd16c/src/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager/src/System/Configuration/ConfigurationErrorsException.cs

#### Workaround

I already have a workaround by aliasing the ServiceStack assembly: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4989#issuecomment-310565840, but this seems hacky.

#### Request

It would be wonderful if the System.Configuration namespace, and with it the ConfigurationErrorsException class, is removed from ServiceStack netstandard library.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not ServiceStack's support. Ask them if they can fulfill this request.

Comment: Question? What question?... :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've moved it to the `ServiceStack` namespace in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/514d95cfbfcf44b822d52995fdcb271e92d1188d).

This change is available from v5.5.1 that's now [available on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Comment: Thank you! Do you plan to also publish the new version on nuget.org?

Comment: @khai.nguyen not until the next release which is still a long way away